# Clips not printing anything

Tags: testing, member, clips

I tried to write the following code in CLIPS for a school project (even though I don't understand why AI is done in this language):

```
(deftemplate blood
    (slot bt)
    (multislot acc))
(deffacts acceptance
    (blood (bt 0) (acc 0 0))
    (blood (bt A) (acc 0 A))
    (blood (bt B) (acc 0 B))
    (blood (bt AB) (acc 0 A B AB)))
(defrule reading-input
=>
    (printout  t "Bloodtype of patient? ")
    (assert (patient (read)))
    (printout  t "Bloodtype of donor? ")
    (assert (donor (read))))
(defrule check-acceptance
    (patient ?patient)
    (donor ?donor)
    (blood (bt ?bt1) (acc ?acc1))
    (test (member$ ?donor ?acc1))
    =>
    (printout t "Transfusion is safe" crlf))
```

For some reason it wouldn't print anything for inputs `A` and `A` or anything else. I also tried this with a `if then else` statement, but same result.

```
[prev code]
(blood (bt ?bt1) (acc ?acc1))
=>
(if (eq ?patient ?bt1)
then
(printout t ?bt1)
else
(printout t ?donor)))
```

The idea is to write a program that prints whether blood transfusion is safe or not.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your **blood** pattern so that the **bt** slot is restricted to the blood type of the patient and change the variable **acc1** to a multifield variable so that it will bind to all of the values in the **acc** slot:

```
(defrule check-acceptance
   (patient ?patient)
   (donor ?donor)
   (blood (bt ?patient) (acc $?acc1))
   (test (member$ ?donor ?acc1))
   =>
   (printout t "Transfusion is safe" crlf))
```